# I want user to be able to enter their email and a unique password i give to them to access a section of my wordpress site.

Tags: wordpress, email

I am working on a wordpress site. I am selling a digital course  on it.
Users interested in the course will pay locally via bank and send me payment details. so after i confirm their payment i will like to add their email and phone number also generate a unique code like password to append the email.
So they can enter their email and the password i gave to them to enter part of the site where they have access to the course materials.

Comment: you can do this with `user roles`. Good tutorial in this subject: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/control-user-roles-permissions-with-wordpress

Comment: Thanks am reading  the tutor now i really appreciate you answer though it seems like a long thing to do but i will gladly do it for am just a beginner web developer and i never even thought about those things am seeing on the site

Answer (score 0):

```
$password    = wp_generate_password( 8 );
```

This function creates password randomly

Comment: i dont know how to use this all i want is manually create user login and send it it to them to access the page

Comment: wp_generate_password() function is in-build function of wordpress just call that function it will give you 8 character password you dont need to create function for creating password